# Keycloak and Docker - Cannot set two types of URLs

Tags: docker, keycloak

I use standalone version of keycloak in docker-based application.

Since Keycloak 1.9.2 there is an "auth-server-url-for-backend-requests" attribute removed from keycloak properties.

This field was by me to indicate the internal ip address of auth server (inside a dock).
The external one (auth-server-url) is used for redirection purpose.

My question is: how to replace former auth-server-url-for-backend-request to solve a problem of having different network addresses inside docker and outside of it.

Comment: Did you make any progress on this?  I may be running into a similar problem very soon.

Comment: Hi, We're using public IP in docker as well. It solves a problem of two certificates in case of using SSL (because you would need separate for external and internal interfaces). In Cloud env there is a possibility to fetch public IP using http get request, so we use that API call.

Answer (score 1):

According to the following links, it appears you can use the same DNS for external requests as you would for internal.  See these:

[keycloak issue](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/KEYCLOAK-2279?focusedCommentId=13156190&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-13156190)

http://keycloak.github.io/docs/userguide/keycloak-server/html_single/index.html#d4e4114

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I have already read it. But it complicates stuff a lot. I wonder if there is any other solution for that.

Comment: Maybe it would help to clarify who exactly is using the internal IP - where are you using it from? Another backend service outside of the Docker container or one alongside the Keycloak instance in the same Docker container?

Comment: Hello, another container is using it directly, and client's browser is using the public IP. My present solution is to use public IP fetched from ec2 API (since we're running it in a cloud) also in containers.

Comment: You could try to create both public-facing and internal load-balancers that point to the same Keycloak-Docker container(s) (or autoscaling group), then use the internal DNS for your container-to-container requests and the public DNS for the public auth-code flows.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL` parameter in the `Dockerfile` or `docker-compose.yml` (if you use them). In other case your should set this parameter in `Keycloak General` settings UI.

**Eg.:**
[image: Fontend URL]

It is quite tricky because you shouldn't set the real front-end's URL, however you should set the URL which is used by front-end. I have the same problem so you can see some examples in my SO [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894298/verify-keycloak-token-from-two-different-urls/67909468#67909468)