# Verify Keycloak token from two different URLs

Tags: angular, typescript, docker, nginx, keycloak

I have a `Docker compose` based system with back-end and front-end components. The back-end is written in `Python Flask` and run in several docker containers and front-end is written in `TypeScript` with `Angular`. The front-end communicates with back-end via Restful APIs. The proxy is created with `Nginx`. But the `Keycloak` Token verification doesn't work between front-end and back-end.

**My `KeyCloak` (and `MySQL`) section of `docker-compose.yml` file:**

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7.31
    ports:
      - 9988:3306
    volumes:
      - keycloak_data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: keycloak
      MYSQL_USER: keycloak
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    networks:
      - auth_net

  keycloak:
    image: jboss/keycloak:13.0.1
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: MYSQL
      DB_ADDR: mysql
      DB_DATABASE: keycloak
      DB_USER: keycloak
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      KEYCLOAK_USER: admin
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: admin
      PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: "true"
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 8443:8443
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    networks:
      - auth_net
```

**Related `Nginx` config part:**

```
    location /api/auth/verify {
        internal;
        proxy_method POST;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        proxy_pass http://keycloak:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo;
        error_page 400 =401 /401.html;
    }
```

**I use the above `/api/auth/verify` URL for every endpoints as verification. Eg.:**

```
    location /api/users {
        auth_request /api/auth/verify;
        rewrite ^/api/(.*) /$1  break;
        proxy_pass http://users:6000;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }
```

**My `Keycloak` config for `TypeScript`/`Angular`:**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  keycloakConfig: {
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/',
    realm: 'master',
    clientId: 'frontend'
  }
};
```

**`app-init.ts`:**

```
import { KeycloakService, KeycloakOptions } from 'keycloak-angular';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

export function initializer(keycloak: KeycloakService): () => Promise<any> {
  const options: KeycloakOptions = {
    config: environment.keycloakConfig
  };

  return (): Promise<any> => keycloak.init(options);
}
```

**My `app.module.ts` file contains the following section:**

```
  providers: [
    KeycloakService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializer,
      multi: true,
      deps: [KeycloakService]
    }
  ]
```

**The getting error:**

[image: Getting error]

**Config of `frontend` client in `Keycloak`:**

[image: Keycloak config]

**My problem in points:**

- The `Nginx` uses the `http://keycloak:8080` URL which is the network inside the docker system (The `Nginx` doesn't see the `localhost` from `Docker`).
- The front-end (`TS`/`Angular`) uses the `http://localhost:8080` URL which is visible from outside (from the users' browser) (In theory the front-end doesn't see the `keycloak` network from user's browser)
- When I send a request from front-end which calls my API (which want to verify the token based on above `Nginx` example), I get `Invalid Token` error
- **Based on my investigation I get this error because I get the token on `http://localhost:8080` URL and I want to verify it on `http://keycloak:8080` URL.**

**Summarize of my used URLs:**

- API's URL: `http://localhost`
- Keycloak URL inside Docker: `http://keycloak:8080`
- Keycloak on front-end side: `http://localhost:8080`
- Fornt-end's URL : `http://localhost:4200`

**My question:**

- How can I solve the above problem? I am very open for ideas.

**1. EDIT:**

If I have tried to set the front-end URL to `http://localhost:8080`, and `http://localhost:4200` but I got the below issue in both cases:

[image: front-end URL issue]

Comment: You may want set the environment variable `KEYCLOAK_FRONTEND_URL` (see the [jboss/keycloak docker documentation](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/) and the [official keycloak documentation](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_installation/#default-provider)).

Comment: First of all, thanks for your comment. I have already tried to use the front-end URL parameter (On `docker-compose.yml` level as well as in Keycloak Admin page). I got error when I set this parameter. I have just extended my question with "1. EDIT" section with the details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have just found the solution!

The `Frontend URL` parameter is a quite misleading in the `Keycloak` general configuration. My front-end is on `http://localhost:4200` URL but as I mentioned in my question that URL wasn't working as front-end URL parameter in Keycloak (I have tested is many times).

As you can see in my question in the configuration of `keycloak-angular` module the `Keycloak` URL is set as `url: 'http://localhost:8080/auth/'`. If I set that URL as `Frontend URL` parameter in the `Keycloak` general configuration (or as input parameter in `docker-compose.yml` file) my system works as charm.

[image: Front-end config]

Note:

- The base URL (`http://localhost:8080`) is not enough so the `/auth` suffix is also needed (The full URL which is working: `http://localhost:8080/auth/`).

Answer (score 0):

I am bit late,

but have you tried to add `127.0.0.1 keycloak` in your hosts file and replace `http://localhost:8080/auth/` with `http://keycloak:8080/auth/` in your  Keycloak config for `TypeScript/Angular`.

Hosts File Location:

In Linux/Unix, its location is at: `/etc/hosts`
In windows, its location is at `c:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`.

Explanation:

1. The Nginx uses the http://keycloak:8080 URL which is the network inside the docker system.
2. The front-end (TS/Angular) uses the http://keycloak:8080
3. You will not get the invalid token error, as you are getting the token from http://keycloak:8080 and as well verifying with the same URL.